# Error deploying WAR with mysql driver to Glassfish4 on CloudBees

Tags: mysql, deployment, war, cloudbees, glassfish-4

I'm trying to deploy a WAR on CloudBees Glassfish4 server. I've followed the instructions at the bottom of http://developer.cloudbees.com/bin/view/RUN/Glassfish4 to include the jar in the META-INF/lib directory.

When I deploy with:

```
bees app:deploy target/app.war -a myDomain/app -t glassfish4-full
```

I get the error:

ERROR: Server.InternalError - java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Platform error -

```
plugin_setup_error: glassfish4-full 1 [main] INFO com.cloudbees.clickstack.glassfish.Setup - Setup clickstack com.cloudbees.clickstack:glassfish-clickstack:4-full-1.0.2 - 2013-12-12T13:06:29.572+0100, current dir /mnt/genapp/apps/1cabb3f9/.
[main] INFO com.cloudbees.clickstack.glassfish.Setup - Setup: Environment{, 
 appUser='app_1cabb3f9', 
 appId='1cabb3f9', 
 appPort=8336, 
 appDir=/var/genapp/apps/1cabb3f9, 
 logDir=/var/genapp/apps/1cabb3f9/.genapp/log, 
 genappDir=/var/genapp/apps/1cabb3f9/.genapp, 
 controlDir=/var/genapp/apps/1cabb3f9/.genapp/control, 
 clickstackDir=/mnt/genapp-tmp/genapp-remote-plugin-1389871636905879, 
 packageDir=/mnt/genapp-tmp/stax-genapp-1389871636.236927/app, 
}, com.cloudbees.clickstack.domain.metadata.Metadata@385cbbb1
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Exception: Exception deploying on 10.159.35.35
    at com.cloudbees.clickstack.glassfish.Setup.main(Setup.java:147)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at com.sun.nio.zipfs.ZipPath.relativize(ZipPath.java:238)
    at com.cloudbees.clickstack.util.Files2$3.visitFile(Files2.java:188)
    at com.cloudbees.clickstack.util.Files2$3.visitFile(Files2.java:184)
    at java.nio.file.FileTreeWalker.walk(Unknown Source)
    at java.nio.file.FileTreeWalker.walk(Unknown Source)
    at java.nio.file.FileTreeWalker.walk(Unknown Source)
    at java.nio.file.Files.walkFileTree(Unknown Source)
    at java.nio.file.Files.walkFileTree(Unknown Source)
    at com.cloudbees.clickstack.util.Files2.unzipSubDirectoryIfExists(Files2.java:184)
    at com.cloudbees.clickstack.util.ApplicationUtils.extractContainerExtraLibs(ApplicationUtils.java:49)
    at com.cloudbees.clickstack.glassfish.Setup.installApplication(Setup.java:259)
    at com.cloudbees.clickstack.glassfish.Setup.setup(Setup.java:154)
    at com.cloudbees.clickstack.glassfish.Setup.main(Setup.java:139)
```

Answer (score 0):

I got a reply from CloudBees support.

The documentation at http://developer.cloudbees.com/bin/view/RUN/Glassfish4 was wrong, you don't need to include the mysql connector in your project.

Answer (score 0):

As I replied to you on our support platform. We fixed the bug on both "glassfish4-full" and "glassfish4" (web profile) ClickStacks.

Sorry for the inconvenience,

Cyrille

Clickstacks release notes:

- https://github.com/CloudBees-community/glassfish4-clickstack/releases/tag/v4-web-1.0.1
- https://github.com/CloudBees-community/glassfish4-clickstack/releases/tag/v4-full-1.0.3